# image is not getting loaded in phonegap android application from server

Tags: android, django, cordova

I am using django back-end for phone-gap application. 
I am loading book image from media directory in django application
On localhost image is loading properly the path is

```
http://122.172.168.24/media/{{book.image}}
```

But while i am trying on server the same application image is not gettong loaded
the path i am using

```
http://www.books.everycrave.me/media/{{book.image}}
```

I provided all RW accesses to img folder and files in it also using chmod command. 
Still its not working.
I don't know what wrong i am doing.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay now its working for the same code. reason was bandwidth for the internet. Bandwidth was too low that's why image is not getting loaded. Now its working fine.